# Entity Framework's Eager Loading populates last record only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API with the following database context:

```cs
namespace Api.Database.EF
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    
    using Api.Database.EF.Models;

    public class ApiDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly string connectionString;
        private readonly DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options;

        public ApiDbContext(string connectionString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(
                    nameof(connectionString),
                    "Connection string cannot be null or empty.");
            }

            this.connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options)
        {
            this.options = options;
        }

        public DbSet<SearchFilter> SearchFilter { get; set; }

        public DbSet<SearchFilterData> SearchFilterData { get; set; }

        public DbSet<FilterStatus> FilterStatus { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<SearchFilterData>()
                .HasOne<SearchFilter>(d => d.SearchFilter)
                .WithMany(f => f.SearchFilterData)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.SearchFilterId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SearchFilterData>()
                .HasOne<FilterStatus>(x => x.Status)
                .WithOne(x => x.SearchFiltersData)
                .HasForeignKey<SearchFilterData>(x => x.StatusId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SearchFilterData>()
                .Property(p => p.CreatedAt)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()");
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.connectionString))
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(this.connectionString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the following 3 models:

```cs
namespace Api.Database.EF.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
    [Table("search_filter_status")]
    public class FilterStatus
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual SearchFilterData SearchFiltersData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
#nullable enable
namespace Api.Database.EF.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    [Table("search_filter")]
    public class SearchFilter
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("guid")]
        public string Guid { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("user")]
        public string User { get; set; }

        [Column("name")]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [Column("description")]
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public virtual List<SearchFilterData> SearchFilterData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Api.Database.EF.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    [Table("search_filter_data")]
    public class SearchFilterData
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("search_filter_id")]
        public int SearchFilterId { get; set; }

        [Column("created")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [Column("status_id")]
        public int StatusId { get; set; }

        [Column("data")]
        public string FilterData { get; set; }

        public virtual FilterStatus Status { get; set; }
        
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual SearchFilter SearchFilter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is how I try to use it:

```cs
public List<SearchFilterData> GetFiltersForUser(string username)
{
    return this.apiDbContext
        .SearchFilterData
        .Where(x => x.SearchFilter.User == username)
        .Include(x => x.Status)
        .ToList();
}
```

The issue I'm facing here is that only the last item has a value it's Status property. Here is a sample response:

```json
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "SearchFilterId": 1,
        "CreatedAt": "2022-07-14T13:16:43+03:00",
        "StatusId": 1,
        "FilterData": "{}",
        "Status": null
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "SearchFilterId": 1,
        "CreatedAt": "2022-07-14T14:04:33+03:00",
        "StatusId": 1,
        "FilterData": "some_data",
        "Status": null
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "SearchFilterId": 1,
        "CreatedAt": "2022-07-14T14:05:17+03:00",
        "StatusId": 1,
        "FilterData": "some_other_data",
        "Status": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "ACTIVE"
        }
    }
]
```

No matter how many items I add, it's always the last one only that has the Status object inside it. Any suggestions where the issue might come from?

Comment: Or any ideas how to debug it? Maybe removing `.ToList()` (and then will return IIncludableQueryable) and somehow view the raw query?

Comment: Does it change anything if you move the .Include() up before your .Where(). Is it the same problem if you debug and inspect before the serialization to json?

Comment: I see one-to-one relationship. I see `"StatusId": 1,` three times. This shouldn't happen. Each `SearchFilterData` entity must have a relationship with a unique `FilterStatus` entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate `StatusId` values in `SearchFilterData`, which is against the configured one-to-one relationship (one-to-one means the `StatusId` is unique in the referencing side as well, i.e. in `SearchFilterData`), hence the results you are getting from EF Core.

The database tables and the data itself imply that the relationship between `FilterStatus` and `SearchFilterData` is one-to-*many*, like the other one. So in order to fix the problem, you need to fix your model and fluent configuration, because EF Core behaviors heavily rely on that, and not what is really in the database, so these must be in sync.

So, in `FilterStatus`

```cs
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual SearchFilterData SearchFiltersData { get; set; }
```

becomes

```cs
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual ICollection<SearchFilterData> SearchFiltersData { get; set; }
```

or `List` or any `IEnumerable<SearchFilterData>` type.

And the fluent configuration for the relationship is changed to (or just removed since the reference navigation and FK property names match the EF Core conventions):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SearchFilterData>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Status)
    .WithMany(x => x.SearchFiltersData) // <--
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.StatusId);
```

---

P.S. Note that if you have used EF Core migration to create database tables from the model, it would have created unique constraint on `StatusId` column, so you won't be able to input duplicate values and exhibit the issue in question.